# Receive null from user object using provider class in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

When user login or register I want to keep the data of user in User object.
On profile page i want to access this object and if user change/update his data
i call `notifyListeners();` and keeps his user object.

The issue is when i call  `currentUser = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).currentUserData`
OR

```
Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).userData
```

Some time i receive null.

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User currentUserData;

  User get userData {
    return currentUserData;
  }
}
```

User object.

```
class User {
  final String id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String userName;
  

  User({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.firstName,
    @required this.lastName,
    @required this.userName,
    
  }
```

);
}

Comment: Have you checked shared preferences?? You can store data and reference it anywhere you need

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences. I was talking of this package.. you can save data and use it at different places

Comment: I know this but i want to use provider package so i can extend it to multiple users

Comment: looks like you need to provide more info and other relevant parts of your code to try and look for the issue.

Comment: How does your widget look like for this code `currentUser = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).currentUserData`

Comment: After login when user obj is set navigated to another screen and i use this code i get null